# F# and memory leaks in simple rec function

Tags: f#

I have a simple TCP server that listens to connection client and it looks quite simple

```
let Listener (ip:IPAddress) (port:int32) =
    async {    
        let listener = TcpListener(ip, port)
        listener.Start()   
        _logger.Info(sprintf "Server binded to IP: %A - Port: %i" ip port)

        let rec listenerPending (listener : TcpListener) = 
            async {
                if not (listener.Pending()) then return! listenerPending listener // MEMMORY LEAK SOURCE
                printfn "Test"
             }

        listenerPending listener |> Async.Start
    }
```

Well, it looks simple, but I have a memory leak problem: when it is waiting for a connection, it eats RAM like candy.

I suppose it is connected with recursive function but have no idea what to do to stabilize it.

Comment: `Pending()` is only a non-blocking check meant to be used in synchronous code, AFAIK. Your code quickly descends into a deep recursion thus eating memory. If you want to wait for connections in asynchronous code, you may want to use `Accept***Async()` methods of `TcpListener`.

Comment: I'm not much into `async` in F#, but I guess you can replace most of your code with `let! socket = listener.AcceptSocketAsync()`, for example.

Comment: Spelling correction: "Server bound to IP: %A - Port: %i"

Comment: I could use while not (listener.Pending()) but if fells off using while in function language

Comment: Are you compiling in Debug or Release mode? In Debug mode, tail recursion optimization is turned off. Also, try removing your `printfn "Test"` line, which I think might be causing your `listenerPending` call to no longer be in tail position since something happens after it. I'm not 100% sure about that, but try removing that line and compiling in Release mode, and see if that makes the memory leak go away. If so, it was a lack of tail-call optimization that was hurting you.

Comment: Why is your `Listener` function wrapped in an `async`? I don't see the use of the outer `async`, but maybe I'm missing something.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that your `listenerPending` function is not tail-recursive. This is a bit counter-intuitive - but the `return!` keyword is not like imperative "return" that breaks the current execution, but rather a call to some other function that can be tail-recursive (as opposed to `do!` which never is) if it is in the right location.

To illustrate, consider the following:

```
let rec demo n = 
  async {
    if n > 0 then return! demo (n-1)
    printfn "%d" n
  }

demo 10 |> Async.RunSynchronously
```

This actually prints numbers from 0 to 10! This is because the code after `return!` will still get executed after the recursive call finishes. The structure of your code is similar, except that your loop never terminates (at least not quickly enough). You can fix that just by removing the code after `return!` (or perhaps moving it to an `else` branch).

Also, it's worth noting that your code is not really asynchronous - you don't have any non-blocking waiting in it. You should probably be doing something like this instead of a loop:

```
let! socket = listener.AcceptSocketAsync () |> Async.AwaitTask
```